# Always check hasClass with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

So I want to check if something hasClass ~ and than addClass if the condition is met ~ else removeClass.

I was able to get this to work but only on inital load so this does not continue check if the hasClass condition changes. Also my removeClass is not working as a result.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.tabs-panel').hasClass('is-active')) {
        $('.tabs-panel.is-active').addClass('HATEYOU')
    }else {
        $('.tabs-panel.is-active').removeClass('HATEYOU')
    }
});
```

***How do I set this up to continually check the hasClass condition is met?***

Comment: your `else` will never execute

Comment: More accurately, the selector will not find anything.  Take off the `.is-active` in the else selector

Comment: You mean a loop?

Comment: take a look to [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Yes, I guess I would need a loop or a timed setInterval ~ not sure the best way to do this? I could also place in a click function as well I guess but I was not having any luck getting this to properly work as intended.

Comment: What logic is putting the `is-active` class on the panel?

Comment: if i am not mistaken, the change event capture the class change

Comment: @LPZadkiel change event doesn't capture attribute changes, other than the value

Comment: this is a strange situation to be in, you're prolly better off reacting to the logic condition that sets the class instead of depending on watching the DOM.. no solution will be awesome..other than loops  or MutationObservers there may not even be any "simple" solutions..

Comment: The *simple* solution would be to put all the css rules from `.HATEYOU` in `.tabs-panel.is-active` instead, so you won't need this javascript in the first place.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar yeah what he said, appearently you are using bootstrap, so instead of watch for class change check for tab-pane click event

Comment: Is the thing that might change the class consistent? Is it something an event can be bound to, or can the class change arbitrarily at any time? While a polling solution (like setInterval) will work, it may be overkill if there is a consistent action that causes the class to change (or the element to be created) in the first place.

Comment: @ Daniel Beck - good point - I will look into this. Maybe the most straightforward approach but I only want this class to be amended to only particular is-active states. I'll look into.

Comment: @LPZadkiel  using Foundation tabs actually - i will try to set up a codePen to play with. maybe easier in a demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Polling

The brute-force approach is to just check on an interval.  This works and is  fairly simple, though it's a bit wasteful of CPU and there's a slight delay before it acts (depending on the interval length).

```js
// for testing:
$('.tabs-panel').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('is-active')
});

// poll for changes:
var someReasonableInterval = 300;
window.setInterval(function() {
  // correcting the logic error in your original function while we're here
  $('.tabs-panel')
    .removeClass('HATEYOU')   // will have no effect if the element doesn't already have it
    .filter('.is-active')     // remove the elements without this class from the collection
    .addClass('HATEYOU');     // add the class to the remaining elements in the collection
},someReasonableInterval);
```

```css
.is-active {border: 1px solid}
.HATEYOU {background-color:#F00}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-panel">click</div>
```

#### Mutation Observer

Or just for fun here's a mutation observer (not supported in IE10 or below):

```js
// for testing:
$('.tabs-panel').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('is-active')
});

// unholy mixture of jquery and vanilla follows:
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if ($(mutation.target).hasClass('is-active')) {
      $(mutation.target).addClass('HATEYOU')
    } else {
      $(mutation.target).removeClass('HATEYOU')
    }
  });
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector('.tabs-panel'), {attributes:true});
```

```css
.is-active {border: 1px solid}
.HATEYOU {background-color:#F00}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-panel">click</div>
```

#### But don't do either of those.

Because you probably don't need it.

Remove this script and eliminate the .HATEYOU class altogether. Put its CSS rules in `.tabs-panel.is-active`, and they'll end up applying to the same exact elements you're trying to set .HATEYOU on.  Any logic in your other code that depends on the HATEYOU class can just depend on .tabs-panel.is-active instead. No polling, mutations, or classname manipulation necessary.

Comment: Less hate is better `$('.tabs-panel').removeClass('HATEYOU').filter('.is-active').addClass('HATEYOU')`

Comment: (Thank you for the typo fix!)

Comment: Thank you for this... in the end this was resolved with simple CSS. You where correct - no javascript was needed. Good to know how to do this in the future though! Appreciated the insight and help!

Comment: No trouble! If the answer helped you you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to the upvote/downvote buttons.